# @font-face Is Not Working Properly

Tags: html, css

I am using the Open Sans font from Google fonts in my application using this import rule:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800"
```

When testing locally and I have no internet connection, the font no longer works.

**What I have tried:**

I have downloaded this font and set it up inside of my CSS file for @font-face,
but it shows all characters are different.

Comment: did you download correct fonts and adding right font family in your css?

Comment: Are you using `https`? If then, just remove `http:` in above import url.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708257/google-fonts-webpack/48310258#48310258

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue.

1.You first have to download the `.ttf` file from google fonts.

2.Put that file in your project and then add following to your css.

3.In url, specify the path of your `.ttf` file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url('your link to .ttf file') format('woff2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to import Google Web Font in CSS file.

```
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800%22');
```

Comment: if you are not having internet @import will not work if you want it to work follow the steps as given by "Aditya Ponkshe"

Answer (score 0):

**1st put this inside your head tag**

```
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800%22' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

**All you need to do is add the font name to your CSS styles. For example:**

```
h1 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, serif; font-weight: 400; }
```

Comment: this is online link i want offline font like a...                                                   @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url('your link to .ttf file') format('woff2');
}            this type......